# Does this counterexample work?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I want to solve this logic problem. I could not find the solution. Then, I am trying to disprove it by counterexample. Is my reasoning correct? My solution looks so easy that I am not sure if I am right. May you help me?

**Prove or disprove:**

**Premises:**

1) $T \iff U$

2) $U \iff (V \land  W)$

3) $V \iff (T \lor X)$

4) $T \lor X$

**Conclusion:**

$T \land X$

**Counterexample:**

If $T$ is true, $U$ is true, $W$ is true, and $X$ is false, all the premises are true. But the conclusion is false.

I am using: "A counterexample to an argument form is an instance of that form (a particular example) in which all the premises are true and the conclusion is false." (Understanding Symbolic Logic, Virginia Klerk. Fifth Edition, page 17).

However, I am not sure. May you please help me?

Comment: Yes. You can get a counterexample by taking $T$, $U$, $V$ and $W$ all to be true and $X$ to be false (that's your counterexample, except you forgot to mention $V$). There is one other counterexample that you might like to look for.

Comment: @RobArthan Thank you so much for your fast answer! However, one counterexample is enough, correct? Is the other counterexample when T, U, W are false, but X and V are true?

Comment: Yes, Beginner, that assignment of truth-values is also a counter-example.

Comment: @amWhy Thank you again!

Comment: One counterexample is indeed enough to answer the question as stated. I just thought you might like to go a bit further - and you got it right.

Comment: @RobArthan I appreciate a lot your idea to find a second counterexample as an exercise, and I thank you so much for your fast and wise help.

Comment: Not sure how I'd put this in logic but X is never expressed except as part of T or X.  As T or X can be true or false when X is false there is no need for X to be true and such can not be verified.

Comment: @fleablood There is a premise T or X. Then T has to be true, X has to be true, or T and X both have to be true.

Comment: Right but [T or X] can be either true or false whether or not X is. So anything relying upon [T or X] being true or upon [T or X] being false can be resolved to the same result whether X is true or false.  So X's truth value can not affect anything and thus can not be tested nor determined.

Comment: The only way to prove X true is to prove T false.  There is no way at all to prove X is false.  So T and X can be proven false by proving T false but there is no way to prove it true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If T is true, U is true, W is true, **AND V** is true, but X is false, then all premises are true, but the conclusion is false.

(You've omitted a truth-value assignment for $V$ in your answer, so I merely added that $V$ must be true for your counterexample to work.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast answer!. Then, with your correction, if this counterexample enough to disprove the problem?

Comment: Yes, with V assigned "true" the counterexample work just fine! All premises true, you've got a fine counterexample!

Comment: I appreciate a lot your help!

Comment: You're very welcome, Beginner!